# Excel VBA SQL. Is there a limit on rows which can be queried, or on recordset contents?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using VBA in Windows 7 Excel 2016 to query an Excel table with SQL.  The worksheet containing the data has over 200,000 rows.

I'm using the ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 library.  Here's the code:

```
    Private Sub TestADO()

    Dim objConnection As ADODB.Connection
    Dim objRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strCon As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strSource As String

    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    Sheet2.UsedRange.Clear

    strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    strSource = ThisWorkbook.Name
    strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" & strPath & strSource & "';" & _
             "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
    strSQL = "Select * FROM [Sheet1$] " 'I've tried many queries, all have same problem

    objConnection.Open strCon
    objRecordset.Open strSQL, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

    If Not objRecordset.EOF Then
        Sheet2.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset objRecordset
    End If

    End Sub
```

This works OK, except that any SQL query only searches in the first 36,201 rows of the data sheet.  Is there a limit on the number of rows which can be searched, or on recordset contents, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your provider should be `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` and the extended properties should not use `Excel 8.0`. If it's an xlsb you should use 'Excel 12.0` or `Excel 12 Macro` for an xlsm.

Comment: Thanks Rory, that worked.  Your help very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm using Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0, Extended Properties= Excel 12.0  and am observing a limit of 65535 rows.   This seems like a silly limitation - is there a way around this?

Comment: Found it.   Don't index at all, just include the $ sign: [Sheet1$]